# Draw a circle with a radial gradient in the exact center of the circle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to draw a circle with a radial gradient that starts at the exact center of the circle. Every google search simply says to "use gradient tool and drag where you want the gradient to start". Dragging is inaccurate, I want the gradient to start in the exact center of the circle not just an eyeballed estimate.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By **default** Photoshop uses the center of an object for the start of a radial gradient.

You simply need to ensure the `Align with Layer` option is ticked.

Just draw a circle and apply a radial gradient fill. That's all there is to it.

[image]

You can even use a Gradient Overlay Layer Style.

[image]

Comment: Aha! Just make a circle with gradient as fill option. That makes sense. My mistake was that I made a circle with no fill, and then tried to fill in a gradient after the fact, and I was only presented with the option to fill with a solid color, or to free hand draw out a gradient with the gradient tool. Your solution is much better, thanks